# Select $(this) from inside ajax inside function

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my code below, I am looping over each anchor link, getting the text value, firing it over ajax and getting a json response back. Its all working fine.

However, in the last stage of success, I am trying to add the response as a class to the anchor I am currently looping over with $(this)

```
$( ".field-name-field-staff .field-item a" ).each(function() {
      var username = $(this).text();
      var date = $(this).closest('td.views-field-field-event-date').find('span.date-display-single').text();
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: "bookings/availability/data",
          data: {
              "username": username,
              "date" : date
          },
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.css);
            console.log(this);
            $(this).addClass(data.css); 
          }
        });
    });
```

In the example above, In the console.logs, I get...

- An array of all data (works)
- A single value from that array (works)
- A full array dump of the ajax request object (NOT the anchor tag i
  want)

Can someone tell me how i go outside of the ajax and get the anchor object outside it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Related link will give more info - but to fix this you need to store 'this' outside the ajax request and then use it inside, eg `$("..").each(function() { var el = this; ... $.ajax({ .. success: function (data) { console.log(el); el.addClass(data.css); } ...`

Answer (score 2):

`$(this)` inside the ajax is pointing to the `this` of ajax success function. You need to collect the `this` object to keep its pointer aligned with the parent.

Here to achieve this try below

```js
$(".field-name-field-staff .field-item a").each(function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var username = self.text();
  var date = self.closest('td.views-field-field-event-date').find('span.date-display-single').text();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "bookings/availability/data",
    data: {
      "username": username,
      "date": date
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data.css);
      console.log(this);
      self.addClass(data.css);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Ahhhh that makes sense. Thank you!